# what is arity of query in database theory

Tags: database, arity, database-theory

What is the arity of a query in databases? for a realtion is the number of attributes.
Is it the number of attributes in all the input relations, or number of attributes of the new query output relation?
for eg. 
Input: a database D, a query Q/k ∈ L, a tuple of constants t∈ adom(D)^k, where L is the language.
Thanks

Comment: What have you found so far, what do you think and why? This is not an homework service, sorry.

Comment: Im confused between the number of attributes that the all the input tables, and the number of attributes of the output table